# Retrieve all video titles in youtube homepage

Tags: javascript

All video titles are in `anchor` tag with in a parent attribute. Here is an example

```
<yt-formatted-string id="video-title" class="style-scope ytd-rich-grid-media" aria-label="Your code can be polluted, here's how. by PwnFunction 3 days ago 19 minutes 84,764 views From your Watch later playlist">Your code can be polluted, here's how.</yt-formatted-string>
```

What I wanted to do is to fetch titles of ALL videos listed on the page. I have tried this `document.getElementById('video-title')` but it only gives id of 1 (first) video. Is there a way to fetch all titles efficiently?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to fetch all the matched elements. You can convert the matched element into any array using spread syntax and using `array#map` get all video title.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('yt-formatted-string.ytd-rich-grid-media')].map(x => x.innerText)
```